Details (show / hide) button in one line, but in a new line after expanded
I have a list with a "details" button for almost every entry in it. Currently it looks like this:


    .spoiler {display:inline;margin: 1px;}
    details[open] > summary {}
    summary {cursor:pointer;font-size:14px;}
    summary:focus {box-shadow: none !important;}
    summary > p {display:inline;}
 <ol>
  <li>Apple</li>
  <details class="spoiler" style="display:inline;border: 1px solid #aaa;border-radius: 4px;padding: 2px;">
<summary>
<b>more...</b>
</summary> <img src="https://www.applesfromny.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/20Ounce_NYAS-Apples2.png" width="100px"></details>
  <li>Banana</li>
  <li>Orange</li>
</ol> 



Unfortunately, those buttons take a lot of vertical space and look ugly in a structured list. I want them to move to the end of each bullet's text. Then, when pressed, to show the hidden content in a new line and if pressed again, to hide back. Something like that:
example
Is it possible? Your help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Note that the HTML in your example is invalid. A details element cannot be a child of an ol element.

Rearrange the HTML slightly to comply with standards and make the details element a child of the li.


.spoiler {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 1px;
}

details[open]>summary {}

summary {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
}

summary:focus {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

summary>p {
  display: inline;
}
<ol>
  <li>Apple
    <details class="spoiler">
      <summary>
        <b>more...</b>
      </summary> <img src="https://www.applesfromny.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/20Ounce_NYAS-Apples2.png" width="100px"></details>
  </li>
  <li>Banana</li>
  <li>Orange</li>
</ol>




Thanks. Unfortunately, this is not what I'm looking for. In your solution, the expanded part is shifted to the right for the length of the word "Apple". Text in my bullets is long (few sentences), which will make the expanded parts to appear in random positions on the page. Instead, as provided in my first post, I'm looking for a solution where the expanded part appears under the first letter of the text in the bullet. I suspect I need to incorporate 2 different "details" sections, such that when one (at the end of the text in the bullet) is clicked, the second (under the bullet) expands.

@GeorgiyShoulga - Right now, the styling of details/summary is in the process of being redesigned, because it's not really possible to do what you want as is. In the meantime, the best I think you can do is to move the img element to after the details element and then style it with details + img { display: none; &:is([open] + *) { display: block; } }.
